# Indicator function of a sequence of sets

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose $A_{i}$ is an increasing sequence of sets with $A=\cup_{i \ge 1} A_{i}$. Then ${\mathbb{1}}_{A_{n}}$ $\textit{is increasing in n}$ and ${\mathbb{1}}_{A_{n}} \rightarrow {\mathbb{1}}_{A}$.

This is my question: how should I interpret the statement "$1_{A_{n}}$ is increasing in $n$"? Since $A_{i} \subset A_{i+1}$, there might be more 1 values for $1(\omega)_{A_{i+1}}$ than for $1(\omega)_{A_{i}}$, $\forall \omega \in \Omega$, but what does this mean? How does this construct a sequence?

I'm definitely missing something, so I thank everyone in advance for all your help,

Comment: For every subset $B$ of $\Omega$, $\mathbf 1_B$ is a real valued  function defined on $\Omega$. One is asserting that the sequence of functions $(\mathbf 1_{A_n})$ is nondecreasing. Equivalently, $\mathbf 1_{A_n}(\omega)\leqslant\mathbf 1_{A_{n+1}}(\omega)$ for every $n$ and every $\omega$.

Comment: Thank you. So for a particular $\omega$, I may have the sequence, 0,0,0,1,1,1$\ldots$, that is, once the sequence hits 1, it stays at 1?

Comment: Yes. $ $ $ $ $ $